# Angular version 17, is it possible and how to connect several preprocessors (LESS, SASS, SCSS, etc.)

Tags: sass, less, angular17

> I previously asked this question, but the question was closed. I don’t know who closed it, but clearly this person has a problem with his head and thinking. What exactly in the question is not clear and unclear? I want to be able to write on different preprocessors (LESS, SASS, SCSS) in one project. The answer to this question should be like this, either it’s not possible or it’s possible and it needs to be done this way and that... If you know the answer, write it down... If you don’t know, don’t close it

Colleagues, when creating a new project @Angular version 17 by the team

> ng new name

You create a project and then you are asked to choose which one

[image: Pic]

So, at this stage I only have a choice of one of 4

And I want to have all the preprocessors at hand.

Can this be implemented and how?

Then add it or during the creation of a new project?

Thank you